Encode piped images as they arrive with real time timestamps
I'm encoding a video by piping images into ffmpeg using the -i pipe: input.
However the images arrive sporadically, but are encoded as if they are sequential frames.
I have tried using -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 in the input block, but it has no effect.
This is the command I'm using:
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i pipe: -vf fps=50 -c:v libx264 -map 0 -f segment -segment_list playlist.m3u8 -segment_list_flags +live -segment_time 10 -segment_wrap 5 seg%03d.mkv
Input block parameters I've tried to no avail:

-re
-framerate 1
-framerate 1/1000
-framerate 50

So to reiterate the problem: A video is being produced, but each piped image is set as an individual frame, despite having arrived and encoded at an entirely different time than its predecessor.

I found a Japanese article while searching the internet and thought it might be what you were looking for, so I am posting it. Please translate it in any way you like.
"Save images generated in real time with OpenCV as a variable frame rate video", (Google Translate).
I consider this to be a way to accept images with variable frame rates in situations like yours. I'm not confident in coding, but after trying various things, I was able to get a fixed rate image as shown below.
(However, I was not able to get a video, and I was having trouble with the broken pipe error 32 due to the termuxX11 environment.)
fpsns = 0.00333  # nearly 30fps interval
endns = 0.0                                                                

if interval > fpsns:
    interval = ((time.time_ns()/1000000000) - endns)

    # capture or something here

    endns = time.time_ns() / 1000000000000
else:
    logging.debug(f'not capture timming {str(interval)[:6]}')
    continue

I made a small correction because I was wrong code part.
